# Nook per device licensing

Tags: android, payment, billing, android-lvl, nook

I am new to Nook and I want to port an existing Android application to Nook. The existing Android app uses inapp purchase so we can charge per device rather than per account. But I know that Nook does not support inapp purchase. So my questions are:

1. Any suggestion on how to implement a licensing scheme to allow per device license?
2. How much additional work there is to port my app to Nook? If Nook does not support inapp billing, does it have something like LVL? How much work it is to integrate Nook's licensing/payment to an existing Android app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just checked with B&N support and basically Nook does not support per-device licensing. Once an app is purchased by a user, he/she can use it on up to 5 Nook devices. No inapp purchase is supported either. Hope it helps to other people who have similar question.